# How to use ref.once with Firebase 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All of [the docs that have code examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#once) related to `firebase.database` are for version 8 and below. I've intuited a lot from exploring the exported modules themselves, but one thing I can't figure out how to update is code like `ref.once('value')`.

Other code is now like:

```js
ref.update(data); // old
update(ref, data); // new
```

But there is no `once` to do `once` to use like `once(ref, data)`. Additionally the created refs seem to lack any property to use.

[image]

How is this meant to be [updated for Firebase 9.x](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)? [The Firebase 9 docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot) don't seem to offer any example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The `once('value'` method has been replace by a `get()` function, so:

```
const snapshot = await get(ref);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once).

---

To unsubscribe from a realtime listener (so not `get()`) you now can use the return value from the function you called to subscribe.

So if you subscribe with:

```
const unsubscribe = onValue(ref, (snapshot) => { ... });
```

You can then later unsubscribe with:

```
unsubscribe();
```

This is what the Firestore SDKs already did, and feedback indicated that devs preferred that over `off`.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! Has something else replaced `ref.on` and `ref.off`? Is there anywhere else I should look for updated code examples?

Comment: They calls that register a listener (so not `get`) now return a function that you can call to unsubscribe them. This is what the Firestore SDKs already did, and feedback indicated that devs preferred that over `off`.

Comment: I know it's beyond the scope of the original question, but could you possibly provide a code example of what you mean? I still don't follow.

Comment: I added an example, and filed an issue to get this documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners

Answer (score 2):

**Heads up (~24 Jun 2022; firebase v9):** While `get()` is the [recommended](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) way to read data once (see [Frank's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345673/2477619)), there are currently some unresolved issues with `get()` where a client's execution of *multiple queries with different filters on the same ref path* somehow causes interference between the queries resulting in the unexpected triggering of events (see links below). I also experienced this and it's quite hard to debug. It is probably caused by `get()`'s caching mechanism as hinted at by the issues below:

- [[realtime database] concurrent queries on the same path don't work  #515](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/issues/515)
- [Queries to the same database path get mixed up and return incorrect results depending on order of execution #6038](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6038)

**Workaround:** Instead of retrieving results via `get()`, you can also use `onValue()` (see [value observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)) and then disconnect it immediately after the item has been returned:

```
const val = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  onValue(query, (snap) => resolve(snap.val()), { onlyOnce: true });
});
```

**Disclaimer:** Note that `onValue()` in combination with `onlyOnce: true` will return values from firebase's local disk cache immediately (if present), instead of checking for an updated value on the server first (as it is the case with `get()`).

**Update from 2022-08-27:**
It seems the firebase-js-sdk team [solved this recently](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6038#issuecomment-1229019548) and with with Firebase v9.9.3 `get()` is working as expected now.