# query from firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get filtered data from my realtime database. In this example I want to get only these once with a specific uid:

[image]

I tried to get the data with the snippet from the firebase docs:

```
const db = getDatabase();
const auth = getAuth();
    
const myUserId = auth.currentUser.uid;
const myOffersRef = query(ref(db, 'allOffers/'), orderByChild('uid'), startAt(user.uid));
```

But how do I get the data from the const `myOffersRef`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once), you can use `get` to get the data at a path or for a query.

```
const myOffersRef = query(ref(db, 'allOffers/'), orderByChild('uid'), equalTo(user.uid));

get(myOffersRef).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.key, child.val().uid);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Note that I also changed `startAt` to `equalTo`, as you likely only want the nodes that match the UID, not the slide of nodes starting from the first match (which is what `startAt` does).

The `forEach` is needed since a query can potentially have multiple results, so the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: I experienced issues with `get()` when executing multiple queries with different filters on the same ref path at the same time. It somehow caused interference between the individual queries where the execution of query A triggered the `child_removed` event of query B (without any node having been removed from the db; it happened just by executing the second query). While queries behave like "sliding windows" as you explained elsewere, interferences between them should not happen. Looks like a bug. I documented it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72738261/2477619).